# Issues with implementing wxpython's html2.WebViewHandler and html2.WebViewFSHandler

Tags: python, wxpython

I am working on a GUI program which some parts are written in wxpython and some parts in css,html and javascript

The codes below is an example taken from http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/MemoryFSHandler.html#memoryfshandler

```
def OnAbout(self, event):

    bcur = wx.BeginBusyCursor()



    wx.FileSystem.AddHandler(wx.MemoryFSHandler) #there is a bug here in this example wx.MemoryFSHandler should read wx.MemoryFSHandler()
    wx.MemoryFSHandler.AddFile("logo.pcx", wx.Bitmap("logo.pcx", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PCX))
    wx.MemoryFSHandler.AddFile("about.htm",
                               "<html><body>About: "
                               "<img src=\"memory:logo.pcx\"></body></html>")

    dlg = wx.Dialog(self, -1, _("About"))

    topsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    html = wx.html.HtmlWindow(dlg, size=wx.Size(380, 160), style=wx.HW_SCROLLBAR_NEVER)
    html.SetBorders(0)
    html.LoadPage("memory:about.htm")
    html.SetSize(html.GetInternalRepresentation().GetWidth(),
                 html.GetInternalRepresentation().GetHeight())

    topsizer.Add(html, 1, wx.ALL, 10)
    topsizer.Add(wx.StaticLine(dlg, -1), 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, 10)
    topsizer.Add(wx.Button(dlg, wx.ID_OK, "Ok"),
                 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_RIGHT, 15)

    dlg.SetAutoLayout(True)
    dlg.SetSizer(topsizer)
    topsizer.Fit(dlg)
    dlg.Centre()
    dlg.ShowModal()

    wx.MemoryFSHandler.RemoveFile("logo.pcx")
    wx.MemoryFSHandler.RemoveFile("about.htm")
```

These codes shows how to:

- to add a MemoryFSHandler and load an HTML string into the memory stream instead of placing html codes in a file and calling that file
- Also this example is based on **html widget** and **not webview widget**

**Below are my codes (trial and error)**

```
class About(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,None,-1,title="This is a working example",size=(700,700))
class Test(wx.Frame):
    """Contact author: contribute a word or send a occurences of bugs"""
    def __init__(self,title,pos,size):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,-1,title,pos,size)
        self.tester=wx.html2.WebView.New(self)
        #self.tester.RegisterHandler(wx.html2.WebViewHandler())
        wx.FileSystem.AddHandler(wx.MemoryFSHandler())
        #self.tester.SetPage("""
        wx.MemoryFSHandler().AddFile("about.js","""
document.write("IT is working")
""")
        self.tester.LoadURL("memory:about.htm")
```

I have tried searching the web for some examples but was unfortunate

**QUESTION**

How can I create a handler for **webview widget**. This handler should load any html string in a memory stream/file (for example using a URI scheme "memory:.....")  so that **webview** can load an html memory file

Comment: wish i can put a bounty quickly on this question...I have been trying for a couple of days on this issue

Answer (score 3):

Can you post your complete code? Right now you are trying to load

```
self.tester.LoadURL("memory:about.htm")
```

But the only memory file you registered was `about.js`. If you want to reference `about.htm` you have to register it first:

```
wx.FileSystem.AddHandler(wx.MemoryFSHandler())
wx.MemoryFSHandler().AddFile("about.js", 'document.write("IT is working")')
wx.MemoryFSHandler().AddFile("about.htm",
                             """<html>
                                    <script src="memory:about.js"></script>
                                    <body><h2>It lives!</h2></body>
                                </html>""")
self.tester.LoadURL("memory:about.htm")
```

Comment: Yes..my error with "about.js instead of about.htm".... however i tried using your specimen above but still getting a webview window that states "Problem occurred while loading the URL memory:about.htm"

Comment: And nothing else? No other message or explanation of *what* error occurred?

Comment: No..just the mentioned window with the message....no python errors or anythin..this is strange

Comment: Wild guess, but try using `LoadURL("memory://about.htm")`. `memory:` looks like a protocol, and a URL has to be formatted with the double slashes after the protocol. Also, ensure you are using `.htm` everywhere (or nowhere), instead of `.html`.

Comment: hmmm.....same error...even tried putting triple slashes "///" like "memory:///about.htm"

Comment: I appreciate your help

Answer (score 3):

What you need is wx.html2.WebViewFSHandler. I haven't tried this myself, so I'm basing this off the wxWidgets WebView example, but you should be able to do the following after creating your wx.MemoryFSHandler to register the memory handler with the WebView:

```
self.tester.RegisterHandler(wx.html2.WebViewFSHandler("memory"))
```

After this, your self.tester.LoadURL("memory:about.htm") call should work.

wx.html2.WebViewFSHandler only exists in Phoenix, though, so if you're not using Phoenix, then I'm afraid your best bet is probably to use WebView's SetPage method instead:

```
html_data = """<html>
           <script>document.write("IT is working");</script>
           <body><h2>It lives!</h2></body>
           </html>"""
self.tester.SetPage(html_data, "")
```

**EDIT:**

I'm adding a complete working example for Phoenix to show how to make it work.

```
import wx
import wx.html2

class About(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,None,-1,title="This is a working example",size=(700,700))

class Test(wx.Frame):
    """Contact author: contribute a word or send a occurences of bugs"""
    def __init__(self,title,pos,size):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,-1,title,pos,size)
        self.tester=wx.html2.WebView.New(self)
        memoryfs = wx.MemoryFSHandler()
        wx.FileSystem.AddHandler(memoryfs)
        wx.MemoryFSHandler.AddFileWithMimeType("about.js", u'document.write("IT is working")', 'text/plain')
        wx.MemoryFSHandler.AddFileWithMimeType("about.htm",
                             u"""<html>
                                    <script src="memory:about.js"></script>
                                    <body><h2>It lives!</h2></body>
                                </html>""", 'text/html')
        self.tester.RegisterHandler(wx.html2.WebViewFSHandler("memory"))
        self.tester.LoadURL("memory:about.htm")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = Test("Hello", (20, 20), (800, 600))
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I am using phoenix 3.0.3...I have been using "SetPage" which I am trying to avoid...I need to create actual html pages in the memory when needed..before registering a handler, I think you need to create  a handler before registering it....this link http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/html2.WebView.html#html2-webview

Comment: Yes, you need to create a handler before registering it, but you already do that with the call `wx.FileSystem.AddHandler(wx.MemoryFSHandler())` in the code you posted above. Have you tried calling `self.tester.RegisterHandler(wx.html2.WebViewFSHandler("memory"))` after adding the handler?

Comment: Yes I did but my application failed to start

Comment: I think I see the problem. I bet your original sample code errors out on Phoenix, with errors about AddFile arguments not matching. I'll post a working example as a separate answer.

Comment: I place all the code in a new file and run it with python....I am getting this "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'WebViewFSHandler'"..it appears that the "WebView.New" Method does not have any methods named WebViewFSHandler....Pheonix documentation show "WebViewFSHandler" is a method of "WebView" only....hmm....can you gave me any web links?

Comment: WebViewFSHandler is not a method, it is a separate class. That is why we initialize it with `wx.html2.WebViewFSHandler`. Try running the following command on the command line: `python -c 'import wx; import wx.html2; print("WebViewFSHandler" in dir(wx.html2))'`. If it returns False, then your build of wxPython does not have WebViewFSHandler. Make sure also that you don't have any builds of wxPython Classic that your Python may be using instead of the Phoenix build.

Comment: I appreciate your help